# Matlab: how to display a confusion matrix in a table-like format

Tags: matlab

I have obtained the confusion matrix. I want to display it in the window organized in a table as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Matlab build-in function array2table:

```
T = array2table(confusionMatrix, 'RowNames',categories,'VariableNames',categories)
```

But the output looks poorly formatted compared to that presented above